# STI и полиморфные связи

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Есть модель `User` и две модели `Developer` и `Buyer`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :events, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
end
class Buyer < User end
class Developer < User end
```

и модель `Event`

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
end
```

Вопрос в следующем: при добавлении нового объекта в таблицу `events parent_type` принимает значение `User`, возможно ли заставить его принимать значение `Developer` (или `Buyer`)?

Comment: Не знаю, как удовлетворить желание твоё, сын мой. Но скажу, что оно неугодно богу, не православно, и вообще не по-христу.

Мольбы грядущих разработчиков, коих Господь своею десницею направит поддерживать твой код, будут проклинать тебя. Голоса их будешь ты слышать, пребывая в гиене огненной, где огонь, и смерть, и скрежет зубовный.

Такой код писать нельзя. Очень плохой код.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev: наставьте же, отче, неразумных овец, как правильно пройти узкой дорогой праведника-программиста? Что в текущем коде грешно, и где найдём путь к Истине?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему Вы пытались сделать так:

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :events, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
end
class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :events, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
end
```

Тогда в `parent_type` будет `Buyer` или `Developer`.

(наследование от `User` если нужно для чего-то ещё, то можно вернуть добавив колонку `type` в таблицу `users`, подробнее [тут](http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/79630/) хорошо расписано)